# empty table when trying to fill it with DB values

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

First time using firebase as backend for web development. Created the front end successfully. Now blocked with the backend. The table I try to fill remains empty. Values im collecting is from firebase database  using Javascript. Below is a screenshot of the table.[image: html table].

Error
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
at (program) (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js:2348:1)
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at (program) (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-database.js:1:1)
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at (program) (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js:1:1)
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined
at  (c:\Users\HP\Desktop\IS_SK4\myHouse_web\myHouse\requests.html:149:23)

The code is ==>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>MyHouse</title>
        <a href="index.html">
            <H1>My House- Build Your Home</H1>
        </a>


        <!--navigation-->
        <nav>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Bid.html">Bid</a></li>
            <li><a href="requests.html">Client Request</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    </head>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background: #92bde7;
            color: #485e74;
            line-height: 1.6;
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 1000px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            padding: 1em;

        }

        .ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .brand {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .wrapper {
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .wrapper>* {
            padding: 1em;
        }

        .form form {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-gap: 10px;
        }

        .form form label {
            display: block;
        }

        .form form p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .form form .full {
            grid-column: 1/3;
        }

        .form form button,
        .form form input,
        .form form textarea {
            width: 30%;
        }

        .form form button {
            background-color: #92bde7;
            border: 0;
        }

        .label input {
            align-items: baseline;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="brand">MyHouse</h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h3>Customer Requests</h3>
                <div class="container mt-3">
                    <table class="table table-dark">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Type of Land</th>
                            <th>Grey House finish?</th>
                            <th>Number of Rooms</th>
                            <th>House Size</th>
                            <th>Tiling type</th>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

        <script type="module">
            const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyCTAL6OnIJbEqOSi8jopSu9SfLjAb1TtoQ",
                authDomain: "myhouse-4ba96.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://myhouse-4ba96-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "myhouse-4ba96",
                storageBucket: "myhouse-4ba96.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "843377498383",
                appId: "1:843377498383:web:9996b1ee834ec89ef6867a",
                measurementId: "G-Q0QWXPT5S9"
            };

            // Initialize Firebase
            const app=initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            var firebaseRef=app.database().ref('quotation');
            var id = 0;
            var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody1');

            function addItem(doors, land, notGrey, rooms, size, tiles) {
                let trow = document.createElement("tr");
                let td1 = document.createElement('td');
                let td2 = document.createElement('td');
                let td3 = document.createElement('td');
                let td4 = document.createElement('td');
                let td5 = document.createElement('td');
                let td6 = document.createElement('td');

                td1.innerHTML = doors;
                td2.innerHTML = land;
                td3.innerHTML = notGrey;
                td4.innerHTML = rooms;
                td5.innerHTML = size;
                td6.innerHTML = tiles;

                trow.appendChild(td1);
                trow.appendChild(td2);
                trow.appendChild(td3);
                trow.appendChild(td4);
                trow.appendChild(td5);
                trow.appendChild(td6);

                tbody.appendChild(trow);
            }

            function AddAllItemsToTable(quotation) {
                tbody.innerHTML = "";
                quotation.forEach(element => {
                    AddAllItemsToTable(element.doors, element.land, element.notGrey, element.rooms, element.size, element.tiles);
                });
            }
            

            firebaseRef.on('value',function(snapshot)
            {
                var data=snapshot.val();
                for(let i in data)
                {
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
            })
            function getAllDataOnce() {
                var dbref = ref(db,'quotation');
                onValue(db,(snapshot)=>
                {
                    var client=[];
                    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>{
                        client.push(childSnapshot.val());
                    });
                    AddAllItemsToTable(client);
                });
            }
            window.onload = getAllDataOnce;

        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Before looking at it:
- Did you verify the request is going through and you get a response?
- Add errors checking when handling the data, this way you'll know where is the error and what it is.

Comment: I'm not sure about 
`snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>{ client.push(childSnapshot.val());}`
Shouldn't you do a `const data = snapshot.val()` first?

Comment: added the errors

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a mistake in here:

```
function AddAllItemsToTable(quotation) {
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    quotation.forEach(element => {
        AddAllItemsToTable(element.doors, element.land, element.notGrey, element.rooms, element.size, element.tiles);
    });
}
```

Inside this `AddAllItemsToTable`, you're calling `AddAllItemsToTable` again. I think you'll want to call `addItem` instead.

I highly recommend getting comfortable with stepping through your code in a debugger, which is typically the fastest way to spot a problem such as this by yourself.

Comment: still no output

Comment: There could well be more problems with your code, but this was definitely one of them. Does what I explained make sense why it wouldn't work? And did the fix to apply make sense too? If so, did you then step through the code in a debugger like I suggested to look for similar problems?

Comment: modified the post with stacktrace

Comment: That is a completely different error me than what my answer focuses on. Did you already search for that error message? As far as I recall importing modules has been covered quite a few times before.

Answer (score 0):

const data = snapshot.val()

Solved the problem